# Did anyone tried to perform unattended installation of Tridion Sites 9.5 or 9.6?

Tags: sites-9.6

Looking for the specifications for unattended install for Tridion Sites 9.6

Comment: I was only able to find docs for 9.1 - https://docs.rws.com/783502/740629/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/installing-or-upgrading-the-content-manager-server-by-running-the-content-manager-installer-unattended - but I am sure this is possible in 9.5 and 9.6 (as we do it all the time for our cloud deployments, for instance). Probably worth asking Support if we intend to released updated documentation for this.

Answer (score 4):

It's documented here for the [Tridion Sites 9.6](https://docs.rws.com/956379/888479/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/unattended-install-switches-and-parameters) and [Tridion Sites 9.5](https://docs.rws.com/816112/796904/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/unattended-install-switches-and-parameters)

Here is the script I did use for my Tridion Sites 9.6 installation it works.

> D:_Install\TridionSites9.6\Content Manager\TridionSites.exe" -s
> -norestart ACCEPT_EULA=true LEGACY_VISIBLE=false INSTALLLOCATION="D:\Tridion" WEB_PORT=80
> WEB_HEADER=sites.tridiondemo.com TTM_WEB_PORT=81
> WEBLOCATION="D:\Tridion\web"
> CdWindowsServices_SelectedFeatures="(All)" cm_SelectedFeatures="(All)"
> CMECore_SelectedFeatures="(All)" CMEGui_SelectedFeatures="(All)"
> DXUI_SelectedFeatures="(All)" TcmSearch_SelectedFeatures="(All)"
> TemplateBuilder_SelectedFeatures="(All)"
> SpellChecker_SelectedFeatures="(None)"
> SDLTridionUGC_SelectedFeatures="(None)"
> UserGeneratedContent_SelectedFeatures="(None)"
> OutboundEmail_SelectedFeatures="(None)"
> Documentation_SelectedFeatures="(None)"
> ExperienceManager_SelectedFeatures="(All)"
> ContentPorter_SelectedFeatures="(All)"
> ExternalContentLibrary_SelectedFeatures="(All)"
> ContextExpressions_SelectedFeatures="(All)"
> TranslationManager_SelectedFeatures="(All)"
> ExperienceOptimization_SelectedFeatures="(All)" DB_NAME=Tridion_cm
> DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx DB_SERVER="localhost" DB_USER=TCMDBUSER
> SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_NAME=MTSUser SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN=EC2AMAZ-xxxx
> SYSTEM_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx TTM_DB_SERVER="localhost"
> TTM_DB_NAME=Tridion_Topology TTM_DB_USER=TTMDBUSER
> TTM_DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
> ADDON_SERVICE_URL=http://dxd.tridiondemo.com:83
> ADDON_SERVICE_OPENID_CLIENTID=xxxxxxxxxxxx
> ADDON_SERVICE_OPENID_CLIENTSECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> ACCESS_MANAGEMENT_URL=http://access.tridiondemo.com/access-management/
> SENTINEL_CUSTOMER_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
> TM_TS_LIST="TranslationManagerSystem" TM_DB_SERVER="localhost"
> TM_DB_NAME=Tridion_TranslationManager TM_DB_USER=TMDBUSER
> TM_DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx

Comment: Thanks for adding the working model with add-ons and access management installation too @velmurugan. I will give it a try.

Comment: @Shravani If that answer was helpful, please upvote and accept the answer to close this.